# C++ Builder - No DragLeave event handler.

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am trying to find or create an event handler for when my item is dragged outside a form, im using C++ Builder 2007.

You can use Mouse Leave and also use WndProc but this will only work when the user is not dragging (ie has the mouse button pressed too).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VCL drag-and-drop only works within the VCL window, and only when dragging over VCL controls.  In order to drag something outside of the window, you have to use OLE drag-and-drop instead by implementing the [`IDropSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690071.aspx) and [`IDataObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688421.aspx) interfaces and pass them to the [`DoDragDrop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678486.aspx) function.